# FD theory and normal forms

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

If I have new

```
  R1 = {A,B,C,D} and R3 = {C,D,E,H}
```

which I know they are not in either BCNF or 3NF because candidate key are not in FD. Now, how can I decompose both of them into BCNF if the Functional Dependencies are.

```
 F = {A->B,A->C,E->F,E->G,AE->H}
```

Comment: 1. Where are attributes F and G? A FD is wthin one relation so AE->H does not make sense. 2. What procedure were you given? Where are you stuck in it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should write that R1 and R3 are the subscheme of R = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I}. I'm stuck into that question. No idea how to start.

Comment: What text/reference were you given? Explain/justify how you got R1 & R3.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a relation `R` and a set of functional dependencies(`FD's`) into `3NF` you can use ***Bernstein's Synthesis***. To apply Bernstein's Synthesis -

- **First** we make sure the given set of `FD's` is a **minimal cover**
- **Second** we take each `FD` and make it its own sub-schema.
- **Third** we try to combine those sub-schemas

***For example*** in your case:

R = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I} (*according to your comment above*)
FD's = {A->B,A->C,E->F,E->G,AE->H}

**First** we check whether the `FD's` is a minimal cover (*singleton right-hand side , no extraneous left-hand side attribute, no redundant FD*). In this case the given `FD's` is already a *minimal cover*.

**Second** we make each `FD` its own sub-schema. So now we have -  (*the keys for each relation are in bold*)

R<sub>1</sub>={**A**,B}
R<sub>2</sub>={**A**,C}
R<sub>3</sub>={**E**,F}
R<sub>4</sub>={**E**,G}
R<sub>5</sub>={**A,E**,H}

**Third** we see if any of the sub-schemas can be combined. We see that **R<sub>1</sub>** and **R<sub>2</sub>** can be combined as they have the same key. Similarly **R<sub>3</sub>** and **R<sub>4</sub>** can be combined as they have the same key. So now we have -

S<sub>1</sub> = {**A**,B,C}
S<sub>2</sub> = {**E**,F,G}
S<sub>3</sub> = {**A,E**,H}

This is in **3NF**. Now to check for **BCNF** we check if any of these relations (S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>,S<sub>3</sub>) violate the conditions of **BCNF** (*i.e. for **every** functional dependency `X->Y` the left hand side (`X`) **has to be** a **superkey***) . In this case none of these violate **BCNF** and hence it is also decomposed to **BCNF**.